# ¿Es posible poner ; en connectionString? Problema de conexión a Analysis Services

Tags: c#, .net

tengo el siguiente problema

Estoy realizando una app de c# que lee un event_stream de un Analysis Services en Azure y la connection string correspondiente es esta:

```
serverConnectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={AsServer};Initial Catalog={AsDatabase};User ID={UserName};Password={Password};Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate";
```

El problema es que mi password contiene `;` y por tanto se interpreta como que la propiedad `Password` acaba en ese `;` y por tanto error.

Ej: `Password = "estoesun;ejemplo";`

en `ConnectionString` aparecerá como `User ID=usuario;Password=estoesun;ejemplo;`

tomando ejemplo como si fuese una propiedad de la connection string

Esta la posibilidad de forzar a que se introduzca el password manualmente pero este caso no me sirve puesto que quiero que se ejecute automáticamente.

Gracias de antemano!

[image: Forzando la introducción del password]

Comment: Has probado a meter la contraseña entre comillas simples? `'{Password}'`

Comment: Pues funciona! He cambiado Password={Password} y le he metido la contraseña directamente con comillas simples

Comment: Me alegra que te funcione. Aprovecho para darte la bienvenida a [es.so] :)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si prevees que un campo puede tener caracteres problemáticos (algo que es muy lógico en una contraseña) lo que debes hacer es ponerlo entre comillas simples (`'`).

En tu caso, puedes usar la siguiente cadena de conexión:

```
serverConnectionString = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={AsServer};Initial Catalog={AsDatabase};User ID={UserName};Password='{Password}';Persist Security Info=True;Impersonation Level=Impersonate";
```